# How to fix fish-eye effect while making doom like pseudo-3d raycaster game

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, p5.js, raycasting, 2.5d

I am creating a 2.5d game in p5js. I wanted to have it feel like doom, so I made the 3d myself (via griffpatches scratch tutorials for principles), and while making it, I discovered a problem. due to the way that I fixed the fish-eye effect it caused the bottom to be wavy.

He fixed this with linear ray distribution, I think, but that is required FOV. Every time I tried to do this it broke the entire thing. if anyone has done anything like this, please help me.

[the 3d game](https://openprocessing.org/sketch/2136715)
[the effect on the wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wohIJ.png)
And this is the code:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(0);
  dv = -408.709660662;
  //image(img, 0, 0);
}

x = 150;
y = 200;
sx = 150;
sy = 200;
dir = 0;

function draw() {
  setup();
  erase();

  /*let img = createImage(66, 355);
  img.loadPixels();
  for (let x = 0; x < img.width; x += 1) {
    for (let y = 0; y < img.height; y += 1) {
        img.set(x, y, 0);
    }
  }
  img.updatePixels();
  image(img, 17, 17);
  image(img, 317, 17);
    
  let img2 = createImage(366, 66);
  img2.loadPixels();
  for (let x = 0; x < img2.width; x += 1) {
    for (let y = 0; y < img2.height; y += 1) {
        img2.set(x, y, 0);
    }
  }
  img2.updatePixels();
  image(img2, 17, 17);
  image(img2, 17, 317);*/

  sdir = dir - 1;
  let columnnum = 0;

  for (let m = 0; m < 200; m++) {
    columnnum += 1;
    sx = x;
    sy = y;
    for (let m = 0; m < 150; m++) {
      if (17 > sy || 17 > sx || 383 < sy || 383 < sx) {

      } else {
        sx += 1 * sin(sdir);
        sy += 1 * cos(sdir);
      }
      while (17 > sy || 17 > sx || 383 < sy || 383 < sx) {
        sx += -0.1 * sin(sdir);
        sy += -0.1 * cos(sdir);
      }
    }
    stroke(255);
    let distance = sqrt(sq(sx - x) + sq(sy - y));
    distance = distance * cos((dir) - sdir)
    stroke(145 - (distance * 1.5));
    height = 4000 / distance;
    strokeWeight(3);
    line(3 * (10 + columnnum), (height + 200), (columnnum + 10) * 3, (-1 * (height) + 150));
    sdir += 0.01;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
    movef();
  }
  if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
    moveb();
  }
  if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
    dir += 0.1;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
    dir -= 0.1;
  }
}

function movef() {
  y += 2 * cos(dir);
  if (17 > y || 383 < y) {
    y += -2 * cos(dir);
  }
  x += 2 * sin(dir);
  if (17 > x || 383 < x) {
    x += -2 * sin(dir);
  }
}

function moveb() {
  y += -2 * cos(dir);
  if (17 > y || 383 < y) {
    y += 2 * cos(dir);
  }
  x += -2 * sin(dir);
  if (383 < x || 17 > x) {
    x += 2 * sin(dir);
  }
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: (it happens when you look at a wall at an angle)